# Convert DirectoryInfo-Object in FileInfo-Object

Tags: c#, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I need to save a DirectoryInfo in a List of FileInfo-Objects to return it to a separate method and I dont want to use class variables.

Can I convert The DirectoryInfo-Object to a FileInfo-Object and then simply add it to the returned list?

Comment: Try this :             DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
            FileInfo[] fInfo = dInfo.GetFiles();

Comment: @jdweng Does it look like OP is asking for a list of files in a directory? It looks like he is looking to transform one object type to another.

Comment: @fahadash this is correct. I am getting a list of all files and one of all subdirectories. and i want to combine them. So I have to convert the DirectoryInfo-Objects into FileInfo-Objects. Am I right?

Comment: @Snickbrack It does not look like FileInfo can be used to represent a Directory (if that is what you are looking for). You may have to create an intermediate object model yourself that represent both and work with that.

Comment: Convert DirectoryInfo to FileInfo !!! Instead ask clear and say what is problem .may be better solution is there

Comment: @mohsen my question from the beginning was "Can I convert The DirectoryInfo-Object to a FileInfo-Object and then simply add it to the returned list?" so please read the whole question before complaining.

Comment: Why you didn't use  DirectoryInfo? Insert your code in your question . When you send path to create DirectoryInfo you can send it to create fileinfo